# How to store Taylor series coefficients into an array in Matlab script

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

This question is in the context of a .m script.

I know how to get the Taylor series of a function, but I do not see any command that allows one to store the series' coefficients into an array – `sym2poly` does not seem to work.

How does one store coefficients into an array? For example, this function:

```
syms x
f = 1/(x^2+4*x+9)
```

How would we be able to get the Taylor coefficients? `fntlr` did not work.

Comment: If you have the Curve Fitting Toolbox, try `fntlr`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fntlr.html

Comment: I tried fntlr(f,10,x), yet it prints output that f is not a function.

Comment: @rayryeng: the use of `sym2poly` (an the subsequent update) indicates that the question is relates to symbolic math. `fntlr` is specific to spline objects defined by functions like `rsmak`. I don't think that it can work on more general Matlab functions.

Comment: @horchler I see.  I just misread the documentation. Thank you for clarifying.  FWIW, I upvoted your answer.  Totally forgot about `taylor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your example, the symbolic [`taylor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/taylor.html) and [`coeffs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/coeffs.html) functions can be used to obtain a vector of coefficients:

```
syms x
f = 1/(x^2 + 4*x + 9);
ts = taylor(f,x,0,'Order',4) % 4-th order Taylor series of f about 0
c = coeffs(ts)
```

which returns

```
ts =

(8*x^3)/6561 + (7*x^2)/729 - (4*x)/81 + 1/9


c =

[ 1/9, -4/81, 7/729, 8/6561]
```

Use [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) or [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) to convert `c` to decimal or floating point.

Comment: OK. What if I taylor series around infinity, and then try to convert?

Comment: Just specify a different expansion point: `ts = taylor(f,x,Inf,'Order',4)`

Comment: `taylor` looks like a pretty cool function. Shame that it orders the components exactly in reverse to any convention I am familiar with

Comment: Since I am asking a new question, I created a new question - using taylor around infinity trying to use coeffs produces errors.

Comment: @Adriaan: It's `coeffs` that does the ordering. It makes sense if you vary the order of the expansion. E.g., the first three values of `taylor(f,x,0,'Order',3)` and `taylor(f,x,0,'Order',4)` ar the same.

Comment: @laozianmao: You might also check out `series` in case it's not a Taylor expansion you want.

Comment: But from the Matlab documentation, all I see is that it's a mupad command and cannot be used for Matlab..

Comment: @laozianmao: that's because you clicked on the first thing that came up in Google or found something in the doc browser. Use `help sym/taylor` or `doc sym/taylor` or make sure you're looking at the correct version of the function [online](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/taylor.html). Same goes for many functions in the Symbolic Math toolbox.