# Series expansion of a function about infinity - how to return coefficients of series as a Matlab array?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

This question is connected to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713271/how-to-store-taylor-series-coefficients-into-an-array-in-matlab-script). Suppose again the following code:

```
syms x
f = 1/(x^2+4*x+9)
```

Now `taylor` allows the function `f` to be expanded about infinity:

```
ts = taylor(f,x,inf,'Order',100)
```

But the following code

```
c = coeffs(ts)
```

produces errors, because the series does not contain positive powers of `x` (it contains negative powers of `x`).

In such a case, what code should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Taylor Expansion around infinity was likely performed with the substitution `y = 1/x` and expanded around `0`, I would explicitly make that substitution to make the power positive for use on `coeffs`:

```
syms x y
f      = 1/(x^2+4x+9);
ts     = taylor(f,x,inf,'Order',100);
[c,ty] = coeffs(subs(ts,x,1/y),y);
tx     = subs(ty,y,1/x);
```

Answer (score 2):

The output from `taylor` is not a multivariate polynomial, so `coeffs` won't work in this case. One thing you can try is using [`collect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/collect.html) (you may get the same or similar result from using `simplify`):

```
syms x
f = 1/(x^2 + 4*x + 9);
ts = series(f,x,Inf,'Order',5) % 4-th order Puiseux series of f about 0
c = collect(ts)
```

which returns

```
ts =

1/x^2 - 4/x^3 + 7/x^4 + 8/x^5 - 95/x^6


c =

(x^4 - 4*x^3 + 7*x^2 + 8*x - 95)/x^6
```

Then you can use [`numden`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/numden.html) to extract the numerator and denominator from either `c` or `ts`:

```
[n,d] = numden(ts)
```

which returns the following polynomials:

```
n =

x^4 - 4*x^3 + 7*x^2 + 8*x - 95


d =

x^6
```

`coeffs` can then be used on the numerator. You may find [other functions listed here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/formula-rearrangement-and-rewriting.html) helpful as well.